# Is there a way of refering to an open Microsoft Edge browser from a VSTO add-in of Excel ? (as old excel addin could refer to IE)

Tags: excel, vsto

I am trying to convert an old Excel add-in to a new VSTO version.  The present add-in reads data from an open Internet Explorer browser.
Since I.E will no longer be supported shortly, I am looking for a solution with an advance developing technology. The above issue is a major point without which this solution ill not be applicable.
Any help with a sample snippet will help.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to access Edge the same way you access IE. Why not use an embedded browser (IE) in your custom form?

Comment: What is end goal of reading the data in Edge?